# What cheat codes exist for Goldeneye Wii?

Tags: nintendo-wii, cheats, goldeneye-007

I just recently found out about the cheat codes for this game, and the sites I've viewed have three listed:

> NotIt!!!11
>  Inv1s1bleEv3ryth1ng
>  <477MYFR13NDS4R3SP13S>

Does Goldeneye Wii have any other cheat codes?

Comment: Which version of goldeneye-007? The N64 version, the recent Wii remake, or the version on XBox Live?

Comment: @Raven Dreamer: To my knowledge, a version was never released for XBL due to licensing disagreements between Nintendo and Microsoft. The question title specifies Wii, also. :)

Comment: @Sapph so it does.

Comment: If there are any cheat codes that are still unknown, how would we know? :)

Comment: Developer could've said they were all found. It's the Wii version, I don't think there'll ever be an xbox one

Comment: Boy was my last comment wrong...

Comment: I know this is old now. But why the vote to close, and why the downvote(s)? This is a legitimate question is it not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there has only these!

> NotIt!!!11 --> Unlock Tag Mode(Local Multiplayer)/Toggle on in Modifiers menu/3 or more players required;
>  Inv1s1bleEv3ryth1ng --> Unlock Invisibility Mode(Local Multiplayer)/Toggle on in Modifiers menu/Hold SPRINT to toggle Invisibility;
>  <477MYFR13NDS4R3SP13S> --> Unlock Big Head Mode(Donkey Kong Mode) in Local Multiplayer. To switch it off, reset defaults.

There's also this mysterious code on the St. Petersburg level. In the archives there is a computer screen behind some bookcases with the code below, but it seems to have no effect when entered as a cheat -- so what does it mean? No one know!

> N6nNOTeKa>> B 3N